# Convert Sql query to linq contains conditional OrderBy / ThenBy clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

`tableA` contains list of recent items that user has accessed, user has option to **pin/remove** the list.

What I am trying is the list has to order by the below query.

```
select * from tableA
order by ispinned desc,
    case when ispinned = 1 then date end ASC,
    case when ispinned = 0 then date end DESC
```

But in LINQ it fails. what I have tried is like the below.

```
_lst = _lst.OrderByDescending( x => x.IsPinned).ThenByDescending(x=>x.AccessDate).ToList();
```

.

```
_lst = (from data in _lst
        orderby data.IsPinned, data.IsPinned ? data.Date : data.Date descending
        select data ).ToList();
```

Comment: try: `_lst = _lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsPinned).ThenBy(x=> x.IsPinned ? x.AccessDate : x.AccessDate.Ticks * -1 ).ToList();`

Comment: I tried this and it shows compile time error, since the data type after ternay operator are different `Error 17 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'long'`

Comment: @ Khanh I think some modification will do, So can you please post your comment as answer, so that i can accept it and will help others.

Comment: I posted as an answer with a little modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 _lst = _lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsPinned)
            .ThenBy(x=> x.IsPinned ? x.AccessDate.Ticks : x.AccessDate.Ticks * -1 )
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you however it may not be the most efficient way of doing it.

```
var result = _lst.Where(x => x.IsPinned)
                 .OrderBy(x=> x.AccessDate)
                 .Concat(_lst.Where(x => !x.IsPinned)
                             .OrderByDescending(x=> x.AccessDate))
                 .ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Also if you don't like the split&concat idea you may try this idea:

```
var result = _lst.OrderByDescending(i=>i.IsPinned).
                .ThenBy(i=>i.IsPinned? i.Date - DateTime.MinValue :
                                       DateTime.MaxValue - i.Date)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
_lst = _lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsPinned).ThenBy(x => x.IsPinned ? 
x.AccessDate : DateTime.MinValue).ThenByDescending(x => !x.IsPinned ?
x.AccessDate : DateTime.MaxValue).ToList();
```